# Upstart, node and bash users

Tags: bash, node.js, upstart

I am having some problems understanding all the mechanisms behind the user management with upstart, node and bash.

What I want to do:

I want to have a service, that executes a node script. This node script opens a port and the server, and when it receives a request, it executes a bash file via a child process.

I have a user named `myuser` with sudo rights.

So here is my service description:

```
description "Some Service"
author "My User"

start on filesystem runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
setuid myuser

exec /usr/bin/node /home/myuser/deploy/index.js
```

Then, here is my node file:

```
app.post('/deploy', function (req, res) {
    ...
    var child = execFile('/home/myuser/deploy/deploy.sh', execOptions, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        ...
    });
    res.send('ok');
});
```

And next, here is a part of my bash file:

```
LOG_FILE="/home/myuser/bash_deployer.log"

echo "User that deploys: $USER" >> $LOG_FILE;
echo "UID that deploys: $UID" >> $LOG_FILE;
```

So here is the result of the `bash_deployer.log` file:

```
User that deploys:
UID that deploys: 1001
```

So I can't understand why my `$USER` variable stays empty while the `$UID` is good.

**I want to make sure that all commands that are in my bash script are run by the user `myuser`. How could I do that?**

*Additional information:*

When I run my node script from the command line logged as `myuser`: `node index.js` and make a request, the information is good:

```
User that deploys: myuser
UID that deploys: 1001
```

So the problem must be between upstart and node, or how I could make sure the upstart service runs my node script as `myuser`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, not sure if it's the right solution, but I post it anyway. And I actually don't understand very well, what I did wrong in the first place.

The problem was in the upstart service, here is my new one that works well:

```
description "Some Service"
author "My User"

start on filesystem runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn

exec sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/node /home/myuser/deploy/index.js
```

As you see, I execute the command itself as `myuser` instead of using the `setuid` of upstart.